# How to set Server path in GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR

Tags: geowebcache, tomcat

I need to set server path in GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR inside Tomcat -> GeoWebCache -> web.xml.
The cache directory is on different server. I need to give IP/machine name and then the location.

How to set it? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Location of cache directory must be accessible to the operating system, meaning that you must mount that folder (Linux) or map drive (Windows). After that you just put absolute path to that directory.

Linux

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR</param-name>
  <param-value>/cache_directory</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Windows

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR</param-name>
  <param-value>Z:/cache_directory</param-value>
</context-param>
```